# How do you add a GroupID Column to a Query in SQL?

Tags: t-sql

I trying to create GroupID column on the fly. Below is what I need it to look like. How do you add a GroupID Based on ParentJob on the fly?

```
ParentJob   ParentPart  ParentDescription    ParentCompleteDate      GroupID
00000111    360120   4/1 Gal-Egg Food Color     2002-01-13             1 
00000111    360120   4/1 Gal-Egg Food Color     2002-01-13             1
00000111    360120   4/1 Gal-Egg Food Color     2002-01-13             1
00000111    360120   4/1 Gal-Egg Food Color     2002-01-13             1
00000155    360120   4/1 Gal-Egg Food Color     2002-01-11             2
00000155    360120   4/1 Gal-Egg Food Color     2002-01-11             2
00000155    360120   4/1 Gal-Egg Food Color     2002-01-11             2
00000155    360120   4/1 Gal-Egg Food Color     2002-01-11             2
00000155    360120   4/1 Gal-Egg Food Color     2002-01-11             2
00000415    360120   4/1 Gal-Egg Food Color     2002-01-17             3
00000415    360120   4/1 Gal-Egg Food Color     2002-01-17             3
00000415    360120   4/1 Gal-Egg Food Color     2002-01-17             3
00000415    360120   4/1 Gal-Egg Food Color     2002-01-17             3
```

Comment: I could put it in a cursor, create a counter and when the ParentJob changes I could increase counter. But this would be very slow. I could do it easily in C#.But it has to be done in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ..., dense_rank() over (order by ParentJob) as GroupId
from ....
```